# JQuery If the href attribute for an element is equal to the href attribute for another element then

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have two elements, a right menu and a pagination menu. Both menu's contain the same href links.

Right Menu

```
<ul class="right-menu">
<li class="menu-item">
<a href="#p1">anchor link one</a>
</li>
<li class="menu-item">
<a href="#p2">anchor link two</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Pagination Menu

```
<div class="page_nav">
<a class="page_link" href="#p1">1</a>
<a class="page_link active_page" href="#p2">2</a>
</div>
```

I would like know how to add a class of "active" to the "Right Menu" when clicking the equivalent link/href in the Pagination Navigation.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: do you want to add active to the pagination nav when you click the equivalent link on the right menu?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".page_nav a").click(function() {
    $(".right-menu a")
        .removeClass("active")
        .filter("[href=" + $(this).attr("href") + "]")
        .addClass("active");
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/JYYPT/)

Comment: Thanks! That works great. My only issue now is that the pagination has .next_link (>) and .previous_link (<) that navigate. How can add .active to the right menu with those?

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the updated requirements (in little more detail).

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
$('.page_link').click(function(){

    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.right-menu a').removeClass('active');
    $('.right-menu a[href='+href+']').addClass('active');

});
```

**note: not tested**